# RDP into windows 7 localhost

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, localhost

I'd like to be able to RDP into my localhost.

Simply put, I want to RDP into the machine where I'm making the connection from.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no. Why would you possibly want to do this anyway?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Try using the program Teamviewer..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a theoretical problem, not a real-world problem

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Well, one idea is to RDP to your own desktop hardware and log in with another account without logging the primary off (and seeing both original desktop and the RDPs sessions on the same screen). Sadly for windows 7 this requires at least replacing a DLLs with a DLL from terminal server. At which point this are likely less than legal.

Comment: Having said that (I do see a potential reason why you would want to do this): As it is asked it is this is about a theoretical problem.

Answer (score 2):

When connecting via RDP on Windows Systems the Terminal Server Client locks your computer when being connected to. Software that does not lock your computer when connecting remotely is, according to my Information, [Windows Remote Assistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Assistance).

If you don't mind not going out of the box, look up your other options for [Remote Desktop Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software). A lot of these programs do not lock your computer and enable you to loop around